# docker raised rpc error: code = 14 desc = grpc: the connection is unavailable

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I ran a service using `docker-compose` in `ubuntu 16.04`. After a while I think somethings went wrong and system ran out of memory and every command I ran by `docker` or `docker-compose` for services or containers I got the following error:

`rpc error: code = 14 desc = grpc: the connection is unavailable`

I checked container `info` and every things seems OK. Also I can view containers by running `sudo docker container list` and also their status is `Up`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I got a backup from volume data by running `sudo docker cp CONTAINER_ID:/path/to/data .` to avoid loosing volume data.Then I restart docker as following:

`sudo service docker restart`

And the problem fixed. now container status is `Exited`. I think docker crashed when system ran out of memory and then docker has not its normal functionality.